# Does Fortify ruleset support ES6?

Tags: fortify

I am having problems with Javascript rulepack 2016.4.0.0007

This rulepack does not support ES6 syntax. Hence, any files which contain the => operator throw an error while parsing.

Does anyone know if Fortify has an updated rulepack that has support for ES6?